# Getting undefined value for function argument

Tags: javascript, recursion, hoisting

I have a palindrome function, as long I do not touch the functions arguments "array", it works fine. Here is the function.

```
var getInput = function isPalindrome(text) {
    if (text === "undefined") return "this input is not a string, enter a word";
    if (text === "") return "incorrect one, you have to enter a word to test for";
    if (text === null) return false;
    if (text.length <= 1) return true;
    if (text.charAt(0) != text.charAt(text.length - 1)) return false;
    return isPalindrome(text.substr(1,text.length - 2));
}
```

This one works fine and is recursive.

Now on the next line i try to cache the functions argument:

```
 var vm = getInput.text;
```

This is causing problems, I have tried to put that line locally into the above function, but it always return undefined anyway. I know that if i declare this variable outside of the function only the var will be hoisted, not the value.

And here is the function appending to result from the function to the document:

```
window.load = setTimeout(function(){
    document.body.innerHTML += vm + " is a " + isPalindrome('tttyyttt') + " palindrome";
}, 1000);
```

I have put the setTimeout there to see if the vm value will be assigned after a second, but i get the same result.

As long I do not touch the top functions arguments and do not reference it anywhere, this runs smooth.

I have tried to have isPalindrome as a function declaration, tried to have the variable vm and even the append to document part within the isPalindrome function, but nothing works.

What am I missing here, all i want is this part(the fn argument)

```
document.body.innerHTML += vm + etc
```

to be added to the HTML.

Here is the link:

https://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/gxwmVE

Comment: `getInput.text` tries to get the property `text` of the function object `getInput`. The function object `getInput` does not have that property. This has nothing to with *function arguments.* You cannot access a function argument in this fashion, mostly certainly not from outside the function.

Comment: That is interesting, as I have read just that here on some similar topic. someone had claimed you can do this, mind you, it was not upvoted or best reply. So how could i cache the argument?

Comment: `var arg = 'ttttyyytttt'; ... arg + ' is a ' + isPalindrome(arg) ...`

Comment: Ok, however I would like the var arg displayed by the value which was used for the invocation of isPalindrome. Is that possible?

Comment: I agree with the above, and in addition to that: a call to `window.setTimeout()` starts a timer for the passed function and then it returns the **integer id of the timer**. Assigning that **integer id** to `window.load` is pointless, it expects a function object and not an integer.

Comment: @ptts how should `isPalindrome()` know wich variable to fill? It may be called from different places, defining seperate `var arg`. You can expose the passed argument as `function isPalindrome(text){ isPalindrome.text = text; ... }` but this won't work here as you want either. Due to the recursive call, you cannot access this property from the outsde before all recursions have been executed. So what **exactly**  do you try to achieve with this "caching"? Maybe you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: You *know* what the value you're passing into the function is, because you're passing it into the function. You don't need to get it back from the function.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks, you are the first one to understand more or less what I mean here. The question is:
Can I access and return the argument after or upon invocation, instead of storing it in a variable upfront?
And then return the value in the HTML.
This would be easy if I get the value from a HTML input element, I understand that, however I am curious whether or not this approach is possible.

Comment: @deceze, obviously I know, it's a theoretical exercise. As in, how do I return the value of the argument upon invocation, if it was not cached in a variable beforehand. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restating your question:

> How can I access the argument passed to a function *from outside the function.*

The answer to which is: [*mu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#.22Unasking.22_the_question).

A function, or rather the code inside a function, or rather all the variables inside a function, only exist while the function is running. Any `var foo = ...` inside a function only does something while the function is executing. Once the function ends, all those variables go out of scope and are discarded. That also applies to the function parameters.

Now, since your code cannot be simultaneously inside the function and outside the function, you cannot by definition access a function "from outside" while the inside of the function is in motion. Either the current thread is running code inside the function or outside the function, it can't be executing both at once.

So at best you could ask how to get the parameters of *the last time the function was called*; i.e. you call the function with some arguments, and once the function finishes and returns to the caller, the caller wants to inspect what arguments it was called with last. And the answer to that is: no. The function doesn't remember or cache its last arguments anywhere. You could write code that does so, but that seems superfluous, since the caller already knows the arguments it gave to the function; it might just have to put them somewhere else:

```
let vm = 'tttyyttt';
document.body.innerHTML += vm + " is a " + isPalindrome(vm) + " palindrome";
```

Comment: Thank you, you are the only one who understood properly what I have meant. Thank you for the throughout explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You have very large amount of errors in your script.

Please, learn javascript first.

Here is a working code for you:

```
var text = 'tttyyttt';

function isPalindrome(text) {
    if (typeof text !== 'string') {
        return false;
    }

    if (text.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }

    if (text.charAt(0) != text.charAt(text.length - 1)) {
        return false;
    }

    return isPalindrome(text.substr(1,text.length - 2));
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.body.innerHTML += text + ' is ' + (isPalindrome(text) ? '' : 'not') + ' palindrome';
});
```

**UPD:**

```
var getInput = {
    text: '',

    isPalindrome: function (text) {
        this.text = text;

        if (typeof this.text !== 'string') {
            return false;
        }

        return this.recursiveIsPalindrome(this.text);
    },

    recursiveIsPalindrome: function(text) {

        if (text.length === 0) {
            return true;
        }

        if (text.charAt(0) != text.charAt(text.length - 1)) {
            return false;
        }

        return this.recursiveIsPalindrome(text.substr(1,text.length - 2));
    }
}

function isPalindrome(text) {
    return getInput.isPalindrome(text);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var result = isPalindrome('tttyyttt');
    document.body.innerHTML += getInput.text + ' is ' + (result  ? '' : 'not') + ' palindrome';
});
```

Comment: I am sorry, but perhaps I was not very clear on my intent here.
I know the above works, I have had a working solution. All I am asking is, can I access and return the argument after or upon invocation, instead of storing it in a variable upfront. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I've added another version of code. You can see an example of how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

```
function isPalindrome(text){
    if(typeof text != 'string'){
        return false;
    }

    return {
        text: text,
        isPalindrome: text === text.split('').reverse().join(''),
    };
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.